# Magento 1.9 Fatal error: Interface 'Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Interface' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, interface

I migrated from a cpanel hosting to plesk hosting, going thru error by error and resolving them.

Right now facing a bottleneck when trying to login to admin backend it results in error as below.

`Fatal error: Interface 'Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Interface' not found in /var/www/vhosts/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php on line 35`

Any ideas?

Ps, I know of magento2 & up to date versions etc. but its client requirement to use the legacy  version for now.

J

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps.

1. Remove or Comment the `Cache` Folder.
2. Remove or Comment the `Session` Folder.

Then try to open the magento admin.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed sessions folder (on server @
`/var/slib/php/sessions`
because that's where sessions are stored. But the entire site resulted in 404.

I also renamed cache folder in
`/magento/var/cache`
But it’s recreated almost instantly.

Any thoughts appropriated.

**Update**:
After thoroughly comparing the files using Beyonce Compare it showed a missing file and copied it over, probably left out during migration.
Everything works just fine now thanks.